# MS SQL Linux "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query."

Tags: sql-server, linux, entity-framework

I have some problems with my production environment with Linux.
I use MS SQL 2017 and Application with .net Core ASP in Docker.

The server has 4 GB RAM Memory.
I set a limit for SQL Server 2600 MB.

(I create backup every 4h from SQL query)

For two weeks all worked fine, but when I saw in Linux command that SQL Server use 2500 MB some problems occurred.

Randomly in EF, I can see error "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query". When I reload the page it works again.

Have you any idea?

Best regards

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, there's not enough memory. 4GB isn't a lot of memory in the "real world" and 2.6GB for a single instance isn't a lot either if it needs to do anything more than basic queries.

Comment: I understand that this is not a lot of memory. 
But I cannot understand why this work for 2 weeks and then when memory increases up to max something breaks down.

Comment: You'll get the error when insufficient memory exists for queries needing large  sort/hash operations. This will depend on concurrent query needs and available memory. Without increasing memory, your option is query/index tuning to avoid expensive memory operators.

Comment: +1 on tuning.  You _can_ run significant workloads on small SQL Servers, but it creates an increased burden on you to make sure all your queries and table designs are optimized.  The Query Store is your friend here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017